# How to change default var value in javascript on hover over piechart d3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a global `var country = "Scotland"`

and I have a method which takes the value in `var country` and sets it:

```
function isScottish(grant){

    return grant.organisation.Country === country;
}
```

I have one callback function called **ph** which is called on `hover over piechart`.

```
var ph = function(d,i){             
            var DOMelement = this; 
            var fill = DOMelement.getAttribute("fill");
            country="England"; // on hover set country to "England"
            console.log(fill);
            bc1.colour(fill);
            bc1.render();
            }
```

I tried like above but I am unable to set the country = "England".

Full Code :

```
"strict"

//Globals (so that we can inspect easily in the console)
var dataset1 = [];
var country = "Scotland";
var result = [];

var url = "data.json";

d3.json(url, function(error, jsonData) {

    if (error) return userUpdate("Failed attepting to load JSON from :" + url);

    processData(jsonData);
});

var scottishGrants; //use global so that we can inspect via console

function processData(jsonData){
    dataset1 = jsonData;

    //console.log(dataset1);

    //Flatten database by adding a pointer to a grant's organisation obj
    //in each grant obj
    dataset1.grants.forEach(function(grant){
        grant.organisation = getOrgByID(grant.OrgID);

    })

    scottishGrants = dataset1.grants.filter(isScottish)
    console.log(scottishGrants);
    //Of course we could make this more general by
    //obtaining a list of countries (output to console)


    var countries = {};

    dataset1.organisations.forEach(function(org)
    {
        //Saves list of countries in countries array object as true
        countries[org.Country]=true
    })

    var countryList = [];
    //Key = Country and Value = True
    //So therefore loop through countries array object and get keys to push in countryList array. 
    for (var key in countries) countryList.push(key);
    console.log(countries);
    console.log ("countryList = "+countryList);

    //And then using this list to return a table of grants for each country

    result = Array.from(
        dataset1.grants.reduce((countries, grant) =>
            countries.set(grant.organisation.Country,
                (countries.get(grant.organisation.Country) || 0) + +grant.Value),
            new Map()),
        ([country, sum]) => ({country,sum})
    );

    console.log(result);
}

function getOrgByID(ID){
    var organisation=dataset1.organisations.find(function(org){
        return org.OrgID === ID
    })
    return organisation
}   

function isScottish(grant){

    //return grant.organisation.Country === country;
    return grant.organisation.Country === country;
}

//Set up a data generator and initialise with 6 values
var dg1 = dataGenerator(6); <!-- Generates the data and is stored in dg1 variable -->

//  console.log(sourceDataset1);
//Create rendering objects
//var chart1 = barchart("#chart1DIV");
var bc1 = barchart("#bc1Div")

var pie1 = piechart("#p1")
        .height(300)
        .width(300);
//Render for the first time

var ph = function(d, i){
    var DOMelement = this; 
    var fill = DOMelement.getAttribute("fill");
    //var countryName = DOMelement.getAttribute("Country");
    country="England";
    console.log(fill);
    bc1.colour(fill);
    bc1.render();
}

function render(ds){
    pie1.loadAndRenderDataset(ds);  

    rr1 = rawRenderer("#rr1")
        .loadAndRender(ds);

    layOutData = rawRenderer("#layoutData1")
        .loadAndRender(pie1.layoutData());  

    bc1.loadDataset(scottishGrants)
        .colour("red")
        .render();

    /*
        chart1
            .loadDataset(dg1.dataset())
            .colour("PaleGreen")
            .render();*/
}

pie1.pieOverCallback(ph);
```

Comment: Looks like you'll need to provide some more info. on this one; if `country` truly is a global variable then `country = 'England'` would correctly set its value. Note that `isScottish` is not setting a value right now, it's simply checking what it is.

Comment: I have updated full code. please have a look. I simply put country as global variable thinking I would be able to access from anywhere and overwrite it but that isnt the case. If you have good alternative on how can I change country value in isScottish(){grant.organisation.Country = country} to something else using other function. please give insight on how to.

Comment: `=` is for assignment (i.e. setting values). `===` is for equality comparisons (i.e. checking if two values are the same, and returning true or false). `isScottish` is simply checking if `country` is equal to `grant.organisation.Country`. I'm guessing your issue in `ph` is that you're changing the variable `country` (which isn't tied to your chart), when you probably want to change `grant.organization.Country`, or something like that. P.S. you want `"use strict"` rather than `"strict"` as your declaration.

Comment: @nbrooks yes you are right. I thought changing global would affect isScottish too. but I dont know how to go change value inside isScottish() because it is a callback function too? i dont know how can i add extra parameter and try passing value of country to it and replace it.